# How many 3 digits numbers are equal to the sum of their first digit plus their second digit squared plus the third cubed?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations, decimal-expansion

$$100a + 10b + c = a + b^2 + c^3$$

I've tried restricting the range of the values but I couldn't get  a unique solution. I am looking for a formula if there is one. I wonder which is the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: what did your restrictions give? we can look for errors and/or start working from that

Comment: I've started considering the highest number for c = 2 (992) but it gives me a 2 digits number. While for c = 3 (993) 9 + 9^2 + 3^3 = 117 so the smallest value for "c" is 3 and the greatest is 9. Then for every value of c I've got the values of "a" considering the biggest and the smallest number for that value of "c". For example for c = 8 the smallest is 118 (1 + 1^2 + 8^3 = 514) and the biggest is 998 (9 + 9^2 + 8^3 = 602) so the range of a is between 5 and 6.